# Android custom listview inside a window

Tags: android, layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

i'm a complete beginner in android so i don't know how to explain it correctly,can anyone tell me how to create a custom listview inside another layout(i've seen tutorials showing how to make custom listviews out of xml files,in which they sets the contenview to the xml files and i couldn't find any tutorial to create a listview which already has other elements) ,what i'm trying to create is a windows with two listviews. When i click an item in the main listview the sub listview shows up which has a TextView, a rating bar and a button along with the itemname,
almost like this image
http://www.zdnet.com/i/story/60/01/054426/zdnet-box-playbook-listview.png
i believe you all understand what i'm trying to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is a split view window with two diffrent Listviews that the one can pass data to another or update it in some way you need to take a look in List Fragments. There is a nice tutorial here : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html